# Javascript prototypes, how to access prototype functions

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

New to this whole concept of prototypes in Javascript and might be confused.

Let's say I have a class called Widget, defined as:

```
var Widget = function (options) {
    // constructor code here
}

Widget.prototype.constructor = Widget;
Widget.prototype.myGreatFunction = function(){}
```

Should I be able to call `Widget.myGreatFunction();` or do I need to call `Widget.prototype.myGreatFunction()?` to run the great function?

Comment: Side note: `Widget.prototype`'s `constructor` property *already* refers to `Widget`. You don't need `Widget.prototype.constructor = Widget;` unless you replace the object that `Widget.prototype` refers to.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification. This stuff is much different than other languages, but very cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideal way of doing so is creating an instance and using the prototypal functions.
Nevertheless as the function is stored in `Widget.prototype.myGreatFunction` you can definitely access it.

The functions defined in the prototype are shared resources and thats the prime advantage of using it in this manner.

```js
var Widget = function (options) {
    // constructor code here
}

Widget.prototype.constructor = Widget;
Widget.prototype.myGreatFunction = function(i){console.log('myGreatFunction', i);};

var a = new Widget();
a.myGreatFunction(1);


var b = new Widget();
b.myGreatFunction(2);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use your constructor function to make an instance, you can use the function from there:

```
var w = new Widget();
w.myGreatFunction();
```

You can also use the function by referring to it via the prototype:

```
Widget.prototype.myGreatFunction();
```

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. The issue I was having was accessing the functions from the constructor. I wasn't sure if I had to put the ".prototype" in there or not.